# Ansible Tasks Get List Values from a Dynamic Attribute Name

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have the following list

```
vars:
  services:
     - uncommon_name1:
           common_field: "somevalue_of_name2"
           common_field2: "somevalue2"
     - uncommon_name2:
           common_field: "somevalue_of_name2"
           common_field2: "somevalue2"
```

i'm trying to get the `common_field` values of the objects in the list.(expected out put in pseudo)

```
ok: [services] => (item="somevalue_of_name1")
ok: [services] => (item="somevalue_of_name2")
```

its supposed to work like this according to many sources i've found ( i've also tried the same with `with_items` instead of `loop` )

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.value.common_field}}"
     loop: "{{services}}"
```

and this too

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.value.common_field}}"
     loop: "{{ services.keys() }}"
```

and

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item[0].common_field}}"
     loop: "{{ services }}"
```

but i get these errors ( in respective order)

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'value'
```

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'keys'
```

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable.
The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'common_field'
```

when i do

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item}}"
     loop: "{{ services }}"
```

i get

```
ok: [service] => (item={'uncommon_name1': {'common_field' :'somevalue_of_name1', 'common_field2':'somevalue2'}}
ok: [service] => (item={'uncommon_name2': {'common_field' :'somevalue_of_name2', 'common_field2':'somevalue2'}}
```

how do i get the `common_field` while having a uncommon attribute.

env info:

```
ansible [core 2.11.6] 
  python version = 3.10.0 (default, Oct 13 2021, 06:45:00) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
  jinja version = 3.0.2
  libyaml = True
```

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through services, you are looping through individual list item within services variable.  You can simply print the common field using item.common_field.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    services:
      - uncommon_name1:
        common_field: "somevalue_of_name2"
        common_field2: "somevalue2"
      - uncommon_name2:
        common_field: "somevalue_of_name2"
        common_field2: "somevalue2"

  tasks:
    # Select common_field in services and print it as list
    - name: "Select common_field in services and print it as list"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.common_field }}"
      with_items: "{{ services }}"
```

output:

```
ansible-playbook -vv test2.yml
LAYBOOK: test2.yml ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in test2.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Select common_field in services and print it as list] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'uncommon_name1': None, 'common_field': 'somevalue_of_name2', 'common_field2': 'somevalue2'}) => {
    "msg": "somevalue_of_name2"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'uncommon_name2': None, 'common_field': 'somevalue_of_name2', 'common_field2': 'somevalue2'}) => {
    "msg": "somevalue_of_name2"
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is the first thing i tried.  gives `The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'common_field'`.  i modified my ansible var structure to have common names awhile ago due to this error about a year ago. right now i'm dealing with some legacy playbooks where there are too many to go editing 1 by 1. starting to thing the problem is else where than code.

Comment: You get that error when you run exactly the code above? I suspect you went down the wrong path because where they have msg: "{{ item.common_field }}" you had msg: "{{ services.common_field }}" that would give you the error you mention while otherwise looking the same.

Comment: i tried your code, but without `gather_facts: false` i need that later. i tried about 20 different combinations , including using it in a different task file and looping it over. seems like i'll have to dig deeper. PS - my taks files go as Roles. not included in the same file.